# Simplifying the URL using ReWrite Rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a blog which has a number fo categories in a `categories.php` page. And the original URL looks like this:

```
http://myname.com/articles.php?category=music
```

Which I have simplified to:

```
http://myname.com/articles/music
```

Using:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([\w-]+)/?$       articles.php?cat=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But is there a way of simplifying this further down to:

```
http://myname.com/music
```

--

UPDATE:

I've sorted out the original problem but now I'm hitting another problem.  My .htaccess is:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex articles.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$                        articles.php?cat=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$               articles.php?cat=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$               article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^articles articles.php
RewriteRule ^categories categories.php
RewriteRule ^about about.php
RewriteRule ^feed feed.php
RewriteRule ^privacy privacy.php
```

When I visit `http://myname.com/articles` and `http://myname.com/article...` everything works fine, but when I go to `http://myname.com/categories`, `http://myname.com/feed`, etc I'm redirected back to the home page. Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ articles.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you so much anubhava, that's a really big help & didn't realise it would be so easy. I've also simplified my article ( `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$  article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]` ) in the same way, but is there any way of making that not show the `ID` number?

Comment: Showing ID is not bad at all, just look at the Stackoverflow question URL. Otherwise you will have to query database using title and that is not efficient.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wondered if it was possible as I've seen it on another guys blog.  Thanks again for the help with my original question

Comment: I've run into a slight problem and was wondering if you could help me out a little. I've posted the question in the edited original question. Thank you.

Comment: Keep all specific URLs like categories or feed etc before this generic catch all rule in your htaccess